# Change colormap in SymPy's ``plot3d``

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

In SymPy you can automatically plot a surface from an expression, namely

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot3d

x, y = symbols('x y')
monkey_saddle = x**3 - 3*x*y**2
plot3d(monkey_saddle, cmap="RdYlBu")
```

to get

[image]

I could not find any `kwarg` that change the colormap. I know that I can create a `lambdify` and then directly make the plot using matplotlib. But I am curious if there is a way to do it directly in SymPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the source code of `sympy.plotting.plot.py`, it seems that the cmap is set to `jet`:

```
collection = self.ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, 
                                  cmap=self.cm.jet, 
                                  rstride=1, cstride=1, 
                                  linewidth=0.1)
```

You need to set the cmap of the `collections` object, and before calling `plot3d()` call `unset_show()` to disable calling `pyplot.show()`:

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot3d
from sympy.plotting.plot import unset_show

unset_show()

x, y = symbols('x y')
monkey_saddle = x**3 - 3*x*y**2
p = plot3d(monkey_saddle)

p._backend.ax.collections[0].set_cmap("RdYlBu_r")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get it working with the latest sympy version (`1.7.1`), I needed some small changes:

```py
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot3d
from sympy.plotting.plot import unset_show

unset_show()
x, y = symbols('x y')
monkey_saddle = x ** 3 - 3 * x * y ** 2
p = plot3d(monkey_saddle)

p._backend.ax[0].collections[0].set_cmap("magma")
p._backend.ax[0].figure.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]