# Grayscale sympy plot

Tags: python, sympy, plot3d

I tried to plot two surfaces in one figure, both with sympy, and change the cmap, but it doesn work, it still using de viridis colormap

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.plotting import plot3d
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = "global"
x = sp.symbols('x0:2')

Fx = (3*((1 - x[0])**2))*(sp.exp((-1*(x[0]**2)) - ((x[1]) + 1)**2)) - (10*(((sp.Rational(1, 5))*x[0]) - ((x[0])**3) - ((x[1])**5)))*(sp.exp(-1*((x[0])**2) - ((x[1])**2))) - (sp.Rational(1, 3))*(sp.exp(-1*((x[0] + 1)**2) - ((x[1])**2)))
p1 = plot3d(Fx, (x[0], -3, 3), (x[1], -3, 3), show=False, surface_color = lambda a, b, c : -c, cmap = 'gray')
p2 = plot3d(Fx, (x[0], -3, 3), (x[1], -3, 3), show=False, surface_color = lambda a, b, c : -c, cmap = 'gray')


plotgrid = sp.plotting.PlotGrid(1, 2, p1, p2, show=False)
plotgrid.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379403/change-colormap-in-sympys-plot3d) seems already a bit outdated. Some experimenting gets it to work somewhat:

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.plotting import plot3d
from sympy.plotting.plot import unset_show

unset_show()

x = sp.symbols('x0:2')

Fx = (3 * ((1 - x[0]) ** 2)) * (sp.exp((-1 * (x[0] ** 2)) - ((x[1]) + 1) ** 2)) - (
        10 * (((sp.Rational(1, 5)) * x[0]) - ((x[0]) ** 3) - ((x[1]) ** 5))) * (
         sp.exp(-1 * ((x[0]) ** 2) - ((x[1]) ** 2))) - (sp.Rational(1, 3)) * (
         sp.exp(-1 * ((x[0] + 1) ** 2) - ((x[1]) ** 2)))
p1 = plot3d(Fx, (x[0], -3, 3), (x[1], -3, 3), show=False, surface_color=lambda a, b, c: -c, cmap='gray')
p2 = plot3d(Fx, (x[0], -3, 3), (x[1], -3, 3), show=False, surface_color=lambda a, b, c: -c, cmap='gray')

plotgrid = sp.plotting.PlotGrid(1, 2, p1, p2, show=False)

plotgrid.show()
plotgrid._backend.ax[0].collections[0].set_cmap("gray")
plotgrid._backend.ax[1].collections[0].set_cmap("Reds")
plotgrid._backend.ax[0].figure.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: The previous code works on my system (sympy 1.7.1, PyCharm, Win10, Qt5Agg interactive backend), but maybe on your system `unset_show()` has some unwanted side effects. Could you test without that function (probably needing to start up your engin again, as `unset_show()` doesn't seem to have an inverse)? Maybe like this:

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.plotting import plot3d

x = sp.symbols('x0:2')

Fx = (3 * ((1 - x[0]) ** 2)) * (sp.exp((-1 * (x[0] ** 2)) - ((x[1]) + 1) ** 2)) - (
        10 * (((sp.Rational(1, 5)) * x[0]) - ((x[0]) ** 3) - ((x[1]) ** 5))) * (
         sp.exp(-1 * ((x[0]) ** 2) - ((x[1]) ** 2))) - (sp.Rational(1, 3)) * (
         sp.exp(-1 * ((x[0] + 1) ** 2) - ((x[1]) ** 2)))
p1 = plot3d(Fx, (x[0], -3, 3), (x[1], -3, 3), show=False, surface_color=lambda a, b, c: -c)
p2 = plot3d(Fx, (x[0], -3, 3), (x[1], -3, 3), show=False, surface_color=lambda a, b, c: -c)

plotgrid = sp.plotting.PlotGrid(1, 2, p1, p2, show=False)

plotgrid.show() # needed to fill in ._backend
plotgrid._backend.ax[0].collections[0].set_cmap("gray")
plotgrid._backend.ax[1].collections[0].set_cmap("Reds_r")
# plotgrid._backend.ax[0].figure.show()
plotgrid.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, but now the figure appears and then disappears very quickly

Comment: Does the updated version work better for you?

Comment: It didn't, but thanks, I think it is a problem with the plot3d instruction on my version. Instead I used a numpy meshgrid and plot_surface.